# Does the transition between +M to -M of ferromagnet count as phase transition?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, ferromagnetism

I know the phase transition of a ferromagnet from order phase to disordered phase ( or ferromagnetic phase to paramagnetic phase). I understand this particular phase transition.
However, in the first chapter of Baxter's "Exactly Solved Models in Statistical Mechanics", it said that the discountinuity for M(H) from +M to -M is a phase transition. Directly from the text,
"The iron bar can be regarded as undergoing a phase transition at H=0, changing suddenly from negative to positive magnetization."
and later on it also says that in the (T,H) half plane, the cut is a line of phase transition[image]
This cause a lot of confusion to me. 
Is from +Mo to -Mo a phase transition? And if so, why nobody study it?
How does this relate to free energy? What order is it in?

Comment: Of course, it is a phase transition. It is of first-order (the magnetization, a first derivative of the free energy) being discontinuous. Note that the free energy is a function of two variables: the temperature and the magnetic field. It has certainly been much studied. The reason you might see the order/disorder transition discuss more often is that it is continuous and thus displays universality.